# Question on the task: Prove $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ is (dis)continuous at $x=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

> Prove $$f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$$ is (dis)continuous at $x=0$.

$$\mathcal D_f=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$$
Let: $f=\overset{\sim}{f}_{\mid\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}}$ and
$$\overset{\sim}{f}:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$$
given by the same formula and
$$\overset{\sim}{f}(0):=\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$$
By the theorem:

> Function $f:I\to\mathbb R$ is continuous at $x=c\in I$ iff it has a
> limit at the point $c\in I$ and it equals $f(c)$.

$\overset{\sim}f$ satisfies that condition.

Is this sufficient?

---

**edit:**
Whatever the person who typed the question I got might have been thinking, I'll take into account the following, as stated in the comments as well:

> A function $f$ is continuous at $c$ if the following three conditions
> are met for continuity at a point
>
> $(1)$ $f(c)$ is defined.
>
> $(2)$ $\exists\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ (real limit, not
> infinite)
>
> $(3)$ $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$

In the case of $\overset{\sim}f$ possible discontinuity could be classified as removable.

Comment: $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$, so how could it be continuous there?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, I was confused by the question, but I thought our professor expects us to expand the function, however, only the expansion is continuous at $x=0$ so I posted it here just in case.

Comment: Yes the function works but the point of the excercise is to show that the limit exists.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya: the answer is circular. If you complete the function with its limit at $x=0$, you implicitly choose a *continuous* extension. And the new function is perforce continuous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function should be $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{e^x-1}{x} &  x\neq 0\\
1&x=0.
\end{cases}$$

To prove continuity, you need to show that $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=f(0)=1$. Can you complete it now?